# encoding Romanian characters in php

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

i have o problem encoding characters that look like this: ĂăÂâÎîȘșȚț
i am using the following mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `NewsID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NewsID`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Title` (`Title`,`Content`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

I try to insert the upper mentioned character sequence in the `Title` field by using the following code (runs on zend framework):

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams(); 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "database_name");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `news` (`NewsID`, `Title`) VALUES (NULL, '".$params['text']."');");
```

And in the database i get for the field `Title` the following value: ÃãÂâÎî&#536;&#537;&#538;&#539;
Why are these characters html encoded? And why aren't the first characters encoded to their utf8_bin equivalent ?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to [`set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: They're HTML encoded by the *browser* (unless you're doing it, which we don't see), because you're not telling the browser correctly to use UTF-8 when sending you data. It's all been covered before... ^

Comment: the problem was the 'default_charset' directive in php configuration.thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I just updated php db connection settings with the following line:

```
mysqli_set_charset( $con, 'utf8');
```

Also i added in html file `meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"`  as @liyakat mentioned.

Old thread, but maybe someone needs to know this.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your IDE or text editor is also set to use UTF-8 characters.

Comment: what does this have to do with the IDE? i am not using those characters in the actual code.they just get inserted in the database through a form.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To set the default to UTF-8, you want to add the following to my.cnf

[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
default-character-set = utf8
Then, to verify:

```
mysql> show variables like "%character%";show variables like "%collation%";

+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

OR TRY

Try setting the MySQL connection to UTF-8:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

And send explicit UTF-8 headers, just in case your server has some other default settings:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```